# Mysql "like" returning unexpected results

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

I am creating a MySQL Query to get the size of all tables which contain a specified string only.

I am using the code below:

```
SELECT
TABLE_NAME AS `Table`,
(((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024)) AS `Size (MB)`
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='Servername' AND
(TABLE_NAME LIKE '%log_%' OR TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_log%')
GROUP BY  TABLE_SCHEMA
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA;

Expected Output
--------------------
Table     Size (MB)
--------------------
login_log 10.0005
log_login 00.8800

Resulting Output
--------------------
Table     Size (MB)
--------------------
login_log 10.0005
login     05.000
log_login 00.8800
```

In the above result, `login` table is not required, but MySQL is returning it. How can I avoid this to get only those tables containing the specified string?

Comment: Your underscore `_` also acts as a wildcard, indicating any character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your underscore `_` also acts as a wildcard, indicating any character.

You could fix it by escaping your underscore in your SQL statement, using a backslash character `\`:

```
(TABLE_NAME LIKE '%log\_%' OR TABLE_NAME LIKE '%\_log%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something similar to the query below:

```
SELECT
TABLE_NAME AS `Table`,
(((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024)) AS `Size (MB)`
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='Servername' AND
(TABLE_NAME LIKE '%\_log' OR TABLE_NAME LIKE 'log\_%')
GROUP BY  TABLE_SCHEMA
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA;
```

The output would be the following:

```
Table     Size (MB)
--------------------
login_log 10.0005
log_login 00.8800
```

Comment: not only login table there are lot many tables, so it is difficult to find all the tables in between [\_log or log\_]@Michele La Ferla